# I want to open an application will python 3 but nothing is happening and i'm not getting an error message

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a widget to open my VM, but when I run it, it doesn't do anything, I don't even get an error message

```
import tkinter
import os
from tkinter import ttk


def Openfolder1():
  open("/Users/admin/Documents/PLAYER/VirtualBox")

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("300x200")

linux = ttk.Button( window, text = "Open Linux", command = Openfolder1)

linux.pack(padx= 7, pady = 2)
```

Comment: try printing something in the last line and check if its printed, also check your task bar and see if the app opened in another window.

Comment: You need to call `window.mainloop()` as the last line in the file.

Comment: The Python "open" function opens a file for reading.  It is not going to open your VM.  You will need to use os.system to run VBoxManage.